# Receive GitHub "subscribed to new repository" email notifications in different inbox

Tags: notifications, github

I receive GitHub email notifications about new repositories on my personal email, since I have checked the "Email" box of "Organization alerts" under https://github.com/settings/notifications.

However, is it possible to redirect alerts from a specific organization to a different email inbox, among the ones that I have configured already? Looks like I was able to change it in the past but the UI has changed.

Comment: Can't your mail app do this?

Comment: I'm talking about two separate addresses, `personal@gmail.com` and `me@work.com`. They are completely separate, this is not a question of what mail app or client to use.

Comment: Given that SE is getting more and more useless as the time goes by, I opened a support ticket with GitHub directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, ok. The thing is that I had opted out of *all* email notifications, so I didn't see the [custom routing](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/managing-subscriptions-and-notifications-on-github/setting-up-notifications/configuring-notifications#customizing-your-email-notifications) section. However, I was still getting "Organization alerts" by email.

So, what I had to do is:

1. Opt in for any email notifications (for example, Actions)
2. See "custom routing" section appear
3. Make necessary changes
4. Save
5. Opt out Actions email notifications

Already notified GitHub that this is either a bug or bad UX ;)